# Passing strings by value in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have two functions, one that creates a pointer to a string and another that manipulates it. I somehow am missing something critical, however:

```
int foo() {
   char * mystring; // Create pointer
   bar(&mystring); // Pass in address
   printf("%s\n", mystring);
   return 0; // There's a reason for this
}

int bar(char ** mystring) {
   mystring[0] = malloc(strlen(mystring) + 1); // Since malloc will persist even after exiting bar
   *mystring = "hahaha"; // Dereference
   return 0; 
}
```

Any enlightenment for my addled brain would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C doesn't have strings as first class values; you need to use `strcpy()` to assign strings.

```
strcpy(mystring[0], "hahaha");
```

Answer (score 3):

The use of `malloc` is necessary, but this way:
`mystring[0] = malloc(strlen(mystring) + 1);`
is wrong, since you can't perform `strlen` on mystring(because it doesn't contain any string yet and because the pointer itself is not initialized). Allocate buffer with the size of your string. for example:

```
int bar(char ** mystring) {
   char* hello = "hahaha";
   *mystring = malloc(strlen(hello) + 1);
   strcpy(*mystring, hello);
   return 0; 
}
```

BTW, you could use the assignment `*mystring = "hahaha";` without the `malloc` since this is a string stored in the data section, and the data will not be lost after returning from the function, but this way it is read-only data and you cannot modify it. The `strcpy` is there to copy the string to the allocated buffer.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers given, note that:

```
mystring[0]
```

is the same as

```
*(mystring + 0)
```

which is the same as

```
*mystring
```

Your malloc allocates the memory and the pointer is written to mystring but it is overwritten by the next line.