# Can you pass a string by value in C?

Tags: c

Strings are interpreted as pointers when you pass them to a function in C, for example `func(str)` will pass a pointer to the block of memory named str. So by default, strings are already pointers when passing them into a function. Is there a way to pass a string by value where you don't have to end up manipulating the contents of `str` ?

Comment: No, there is no such thing in C. Unless you put your string into a `struct`. Structs can be passed by value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing strings by value in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608386/passing-strings-by-value-in-c)

Comment: What do you mean with "don't have to end up manipulating the contents of str"? Isn't that kind of the purpose of most string handling functions, to "manipulate the contents" of a string? It doesn't matter if you have an array (what one could consider a string "value") and a pointer to the first characters of a string, they are all handled in the exact same way. What is the reason you want to pass a string by value? What is the problem that's supposed to solve?

Comment: You can pass the string in a `struct` but the length of the array of `char` inside the `struct` would need to be specified, limiting the length of a null-terminated string that would fit in it.

Comment: Well if you want an unmutable string even if it's a pointer just declare it as a constant

Comment: If the function is not going to modify the string, then why is it important to pass it by value?

Comment: No, strings are not pointers also not when they are passed to a function. The string object decays to a pointer when used, just like any array.

Comment: ... including when it is passed to a function, @12431234123412341234123.  I don't see what distinction you're drawing there.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The string still exist as an object. The pointer is not the string, the pointer points to the string.

Comment: I read the question as the function *is* modifying the string in the formal parameter and OP wants to avoid modifying the string in the function call argument.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123, Ok, I see that the OP's language is a little loose there, but I don't think they have any actual misunderstanding.

Comment: If the function needs to work on a copy of the string, an alternative to using some `struct` to pass by value is to pass a `const char *` and copy the string inside the function.

Answer (score 7):

First, what is a string? It's an array of characters and then a `\0`. Just to make sure we all agree on that.

So the question is, can you pass an array of characters by value? And the answer is yes, but only if it's inside a struct or union:

```
struct String40Chars {
    char str[41];
};

void f(struct String40Chars s) {
    // s was passed by value - including s.str
}
```

However, you can't pass an array directly due to a historical quirk:

```
void f(char str[41]) {
    // you would think this would work,
    // but actually, the compiler converts it to void f(char *str)
}
```

That is unfortunate for people who really do want to pass arrays by value.

Luckily you usually don't need to. In every case I can think of, a pointer is good enough, and faster as well since it doesn't need to copy the array. Maybe you can elaborate on why you need to pass an array by value.

P.S. You talk about "strings being pointers" but that is nonsense. Strings are arrays. You can have pointers to arrays but the pointer is not the array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Honestly, I have no idea why I would want to pass a string by value lol. It's one of the questions for my uni assignment. Got mad confused when I read the question, "pass a string by value? wth how does that work?". Anyways, cheers.

Comment: Small quibble: a string is an array of characters "terminated by *and including* the first null character (§7.1.1). Which means that `s[strlen(s)]` is 0, and that `s + strlen(s) + 1` is a valid address, although not dereferenceable.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to achieve value semantics with string arguments in C is to have a struct or union that wraps the string.

Something like:

```
#define STR_BY_VALUE_MAX_LENGTH 128
typedef struct StrByValue_
{
    char str[STR_BY_VALUE_MAX_LENGTH];
} StrByValue;

void f(StrByValue strByVal)
{
    // Changes to strByVal will not affect the caller
}
```

Of course the caller will have to initialize the `StrByValue` object by copying the string (e.g. using strcpy) into the `str` field. You can also add a `len` field to the `StrByValue` struct if you don't want to use zero terminated strings.

Answer (score 0):

Other answer are storing the string on the stack memory, which cannot be resized after initialization, which I don't think is a long runner. According to me string should be stored on heap memory so that we can expand it later, think something of a data structure that expands when something is appended at the end.

To implement this nicely and with some sugar syntax, we need to create 3 functions namely `init_string()`, `append_string()` and `free_string()`.

- `init_string()`: initialize the pointer and assign `len = INIT_STR_LEN`
- `append_string()`: can be used for concatenation of two strings
- `free_string()`: free the heap allocated `ptr`, hence no memory leaks

##### Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *ptr;
    size_t len;
} string;

string init_string(const char *s)
{
    string x;
    x.len = strlen(s);
    x.ptr = malloc(x.len + 1);
    if (!x.ptr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "err: memory can't be allocated\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memcpy(x.ptr, s, x.len + 1);
    return x;
}

void append_string(string *s, const char *str)
{
    if (!str || !s)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "err: null was passed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    size_t str_l = strlen(str);
    s->ptr = realloc(s->ptr, s->len + str_l + 1);
    if (!s->ptr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "err: memory can't be allocated\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memcpy(s->ptr + s->len, str, str_l + 1);
    s->len += str_l;
}

void free_string(string *s)
{
    if (!s)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "err: null was passed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    free(s->ptr);
    s->len = 0;
}

void foo(string a) // got the value of a
{
    // cannot modified permanently
}

void bar(string *a) // got the address of a
{
    // can be modified permanently
}

int main(void)
{
    string str = init_string("Hello world, I'm a c-string.");
    puts(str.ptr);
    append_string(&str, "stackoverflow");
    puts(str.ptr);
    free_string(&str);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```